# To copy a file and preserve its comment

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, extended-attributes

Is it possible to copy an individual file and preserve its comment?

Here is what I have tried. Nothing here works for me on macOS 14.3.1 and Zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0).

```
cp file.txt file-copy.txt
cp -a file.txt file-copy.txt
rsync file.txt file-copy.txt
rsync -E file.txt file-copy.txt
```

The tags (red, orange, etc.) are always preserved, but not the comment.

If you run `xattr file-copy.txt`, you will see that the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment` extended attribute itself is preserved, but if you run `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment file-copy.txt` you will see that its value is `""`.

Comment: This is a bit of a side-step but applescript can `duplicate` a file and the result will have whatever finder comment that the original did. An example command would be `tell application "Finder" to duplicate file "file.txt" of folder folderPath`, where _folderPath_ would be the path to the file's containing folder. It is possible to call applescript from the shell using the `osascript` command. It's a bit quirky but depending upon your specific use case, it might provide a solution. `Duplicate` has several options which can be found in its applescript dictionary, and there is `man osascript`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finder Comments** are a mess and unreliable. The best source for this is Howard Oakley's [Would you like to Comment or Finder Comment?](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/05/27/would-you-like-to-comment-or-finder-comment/)

Originally Finder Comments were stored in the folder in the `.DS_Store` file.  Since macOS (I don't know which version) they are often stored in the file's extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment`.  But can continue to be in `.DS_Store` as well or instead.

The extended attribute belongs to the file and is kept with the file when moving or copying. The Finder Comment in .DS_Store belongs to a conjunction of folder and file; that is broken when you move the file and needs to created afresh in the `.DS_Store` of the new folder.

Copying (and duplicating) is hopelessly unreliable for Finder Comments - see Howard Oakley's post.

Note that Spotlight may use Finder Comments stored in either `.DS_Store` or as an extended attribute.  Both sources are used to populate `mdls`'s `kMDItemFinderComment`. As a result `mdls` is not a reliable indicator of what is going on.

A better solution is to use file **Comments** which are stored as the `kMDItemComment` extended attribute (and move with the file) and are sometimes displayed by Finder in Get Info's More Info section.  But more reliably shown using `xattr` or `mdls` and, of course, are available to Spotlight searches,

You say in your final paragraph: If you run `xattr file-copy.txt`, you will see that the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment` extended attribute itself is preserved, but if you run `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment file-copy.txt` you will see that its value is "".

What I think has happened is that the extended attribute has been copied with the file, but a new blank Finder Comment has been created in `.DS_Store`. And then Spotlight has used the blank one in `.DS_Store` - and this is what `mdls` shows.  Remember that `mdls` reports metadata in the spotlight index and not directly the content of extended attributes or .DS_Store. It can, for Finder Comments, be populated from either `.DS_Store` or from the file's extended attribute.

In conclusion: don't use Finder Comments.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ditto` with no arguments instead of `cp` to get metadata copied for command line file duplication tasks.

There appears to be a finder bug where a file with legitimate kMDItemFinderComment metadata is not shows in Finder. I have yet to isolate why / how / when that happens or if it's truly a bug on some versions of macOS including 14.4.

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed, `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment file-copy.txt` returns the comment, it works. But the comment still missing in the Finder, in the Get Info window. (`killall Finder` doesn't seem to solve this.) Do you see it there?

Comment: I do not see the comment in finder. Strange days! I wonder what’s up here…

Comment: `cp -p` appears to have the same effect as `ditto` - including comments showing up in `mdls` but not in Finder.

Comment: I’m surprised about the copy not working in /tmp and Finder not showing a comment that `mdls` shows. Very strange indeed @Gairfowl

Comment: @Mike I think it would be fair to temporary "deaccept" the answer. Maybe someone could edit/improve it, so that it will work for Finder too.

Comment: @Gairfowl What is strange to me is that currently `cp -p` _does_ preserve mdls-readable comments. But when I tested it yesterday and today, many times, in the same folder (`~/john/john_/test`), the result was `""` (the empty string) (as described in my original question). Maybe because I was in a hurry or something like this, not sure.

Comment: @jsx97 Please go ahead and remove the accept. [I also edited my post.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/471024/edit) Let's see if anyone has more insight! You are encouraged to always edit / use those tools and having an "accept" may make some people not answer, Usually the people that know excellent answers will always post regardless of another accept, but it could help.

Comment: FWIW, I have noticed Finder being ***very*** slow at updating metadata, possibly relying on caches too much.

Comment: Even failing to show this after shutting down the OS @benwiggy in my book, it’s a true bug if the OS can’t render data that was recorded to disk before the OS started up and the test happens.

Comment: The issue seems to be rooted in `.DS_Store`. Create a folder with two files, one of which has a tag and another has a comment. If you copy its content to another folder without hidden files, the comment will be lost: `cp -a folder/* another-folder`. But if you copy its content _with_ hidden files, the comment will be preserved: `cp -a folder/*(DN) another-folder`. Then, to be able to see that comment in the Get Info window, you need to relaunch Finder: `killall Finder`.

Comment: When copying individual files, relaunching Finder doesn't restore comments, and so we probably have to edit `.DS_Store` somehow.

Comment: Not, I suggest, a bug in Finder. Rather that spotlight indexing is indeterminate as to whether the xattr or .DS_Store is used as source of mdls/spotlight Finder Comment.